# extracting row labels (?) from a data.frame

Tags: r, dataframe

Starting with a data.frame...

```
df = data.frame(k=c(1,5,4,7,6), v=c(3,1,4,1,5))
> df
  k v
1 1 3
2 5 1
3 4 4
4 7 1
5 6 5
```

I might run some number of arbitrary manipulations...

```
> foo1 = df[df$k>3,]
> foo2 = head(foo1[order(foo1$v),], 2)
> foo2
  k v
2 5 1
4 7 1
```

At this point `foo2` has somehow retained the original row numbers from`df` (in this case 2 and 4).

How do I extract these?

```
> insert_magic_function_here(foo2)
[1] 2 4
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think you're looking for `rownames`.

Comment: This deserves the additional caveat that referencing `foo2[2,]` will not give you the row labeled `2`.  It will instead give you the second row in the data.frame `foo2` which labeled `4`.

Comment: @Justin true. but works for exactly how i want to use which is `df[as.numeric(rownames(foo2)),]`

Comment: `foo2["2", ]` should return the first row in foo2. The rownames are 'character' despite appearances to the contrary.

Comment: Isn't `df[as.numeric(rownames(foo2)),]` just the same as `foo2` though?

Comment: @TimP in this case yes, but this one was contrived. my actual problem case was vastly more complex with many more steps and additional and remove columns.

Comment: In situations such as that I'd recommend setting aside a column as a unique ID column for each row - ideally a primary key derived from the data, but an integer code would suffice - and then whichever ids are left in 'foo2' at the end of the process tell you the rows you want in the original data (just match on id). This would help to keep the code robust to data changes at a later date and give additional piece of mind that everything's worked correctly.